# How to find table engine in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql

I've just installed MySQL Workbench 5.2.39 and I'm currently viewing one of my databases through the 'Schema' panel in a 'SQL Editor' tab. I can see all of my database's tables under 'Tables', but no indication of what engine they use. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to see the storage engine of a table

### METHOD #1

Step 01) Double Click on which Connection you want to open (Opens SQL Editor)

Step 02) Click on the Database

Step 03) Right Click on the Table (menu pops up)

Step 04) Click on Send to SQL Editor (menu appears sideways)

Step 05) Click Create Statement

You will see the CREATE TABLE SQL command. At the bottom of the Command is the part that says `ENGINE=`.

### METHOD #2

Another way to display the engine of a table is to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database

For a table mydb.mytable, run this to see the engine

```
SELECT engine FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Both methods work, but it seems like a glaring omission from the GUI to not mention somewhere the engine type! Compared to the previous MySQL Administrator Toolkit.